# How to clone an sqlite database to another encoding

Tags: sqlite

I have created an sqlite database without concerning its encoding because i mostly had integers.
I decided to add some string columns and realized that my encoding is not UTF-8.
The documentation says that i cannot change the encoding to an existing database, neither attach one with different encoding to transfer all my data (http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding).
Is it possible to easily create one UTF-8 database and move all my data into the new one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed already, there's no one-click solution (look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532532/check-the-encoding-of-text-in-sqlite)), but fortunately a workaround is not so complicated.

1. Dump or export your current database into an *.sql file
2. Create db with correct encoding
3. Import data running checked (and corrected) exported sql file.