# Need to insert huge data into sqlite table from insert statement

Tags: sqlite, insert

I have got a statment like this

```
INSERT INTO 'tablename' ('column1', 'column2') VALUES
('data1', 'data2'),
('data1', 'data2'),
('data1', 'data2'),
('data1', 'data2');
```

But it contents a huge amount of data (about 100 000) (it was exported like this from other database).
Does anybody know a way to insert this data into table? Any way will help. This is just one operation, not for program, etc..
All sqlite managers I use just hanged up.

I read here that sqlite does not support such statements, so may be I need a way to convert statement in something usable.. may be trought other DB type..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use .import command.

```
 .import FILE TABLE     Import data from FILE into TABLE
```

There is a HUGE speed difference between using individual sql statements and .import in sqlite.

Use pragma encoding [Check the encoding of text in SQlite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4532532/41782)

Comment: thank you, it works and very fast! it was imported, but the locale of the string in our language is wrong..