# How to import file with non-printable characters using SQLite?

Tags: sql, bash, import, sqlite

I have this file which has non-printable characters (I've saved it in UTF-8 format):
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/110553980/mifile.txt

Then I would like to load it into SQLite DB by this way (following this tip I've found: [Check the encoding of text in SQlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532532/check-the-encoding-of-text-in-sqlite)):

```
PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8"; 

CREATE TABLE t (
NUMERO_REGISTRO INTEGER
, RW_FECHA1 TEXT
, RW_EMISOR1 TEXT
, RW_IAMAT TEXT
, RW_GRUPO TEXT
, RW_NOMIAT TEXT
, RW_GAASADES1 TEXT
, RW_PAISDEST1 TEXT
, RW_MARCA_ALTO_ING TEXT
, RW_IBTACU_ACT TEXT
, RW_IBACU_ACT TEXT
, RW_IIBACU_ACT TEXT
, RW_IINACU_ACT TEXT
, RW_IBTACU_ANT TEXT
, RW_IBACU_ANT TEXT
, RW_IIBACU_ANT TEXT
, RW_IINACU_ANT TEXT
, RW_MARCA_CRECI TEXT
, RW_MARCA_ACU TEXT
, RW_DELE_EMI TEXT
, RW_DISTRITO TEXT
, RW_DIREMI TEXT
, RW_POBEMI TEXT
, RW_PROVINCIA TEXT
, RW_DELEGACION_ACU TEXT
, RW_DISTRITO_ACU TEXT
, RW_ZONA_VENTA_ACU TEXT
, RW_VENDEDOR_ACU TEXT
, RW_CONTRATO TEXT
, RW_NRO_SERIE TEXT
, RW_OD_ACT TEXT
, RW_OD_ANT TEXT
, RW_OD_N1_ACT TEXT
, RW_OD_N1_ANT TEXT
, RW_OD_N2_ACT TEXT
, RW_OD_N2_ANT TEXT
, RW_JB TEXT
, RW_CIA TEXT
, RW_SPAM TEXT
);

.separator 'ww'
.import /home/llami/mifile.txt TABLA
```

But It returns the following when I run it under my RedHat Linux server:

```
$ sqlite3 dbname.db < /home/llami/loadit.sql
Error: /home/llami/mifile.txt line 1: expected 39 columns of data but found 10
```

I think is becouse it can't read the special characters and somehow it interprets them like the end of the record.

How could I import this file? I dislike the alternative of adding insert-into to the sql script becouse the real file I want to load has more than 2.000.000 records, so the performance is a very important point.

Comment: Sqlite3 doesn't allow multi-byte input separators (at least in recent versions); the code doesn't seem to care about non-ascii characters, though. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.6.20 version. If a single byte separator (and adapt the file) the I have `line 1: expected 39 columns of data but found 24`.

Comment: The null character is not allowed in text values. `.import` does not work with arbitrary binary data. Why are using VARCHAR for binary columns?

Comment: Thanks @CL.! But I've tried to change it to TEXT and even BLOB, but it returns the same error...

Comment: The actual problem is not the column's data type (which [does not matter](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) anyway), but `.import`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of sqlite3 in use (3.6.20, according to a comment) does not allow NUL bytes in `.import`ed data, so the each input line is terminated by the first NUL byte. It does, on the other hand, accept multi-character separators.

More recent versions of sqlite3 do not allow multi-character separators, but appear to handle NUL bytes. However, `TEXT` fields are probably not suitable containers for strings containing NUL bytes; I'd suggest using `BLOB`s.

By the way, in 3.6.20, `.import` works by creating an `INSERT INTO 'table' VALUES(...)` command and executing it, so with that version you are not actually saving anything by using the `.import` facility. It would be just as fast to create the `INSERT` command yourself and execute it, and that would have the advantage of letting you do whatever is needed to accurately create the data.