# Replace � characters in sqlite3

Tags: sql, unicode, replace, sqlite

I have a table imported from a CSV with data containing the character "ñ (HTML entity `&#241;`) (example: `Niño`). But after import, the table shows a "black diamond with question mark" character (`�`) in place of this `ñ` character. I tried doing this but no effect:

```
UPDATE myTable SET name=REPLACE(name, "�", "ñ");
```

Comment: You need to change the encoding of your database to something which supports accented characters.  UTF-8 should do fine.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532532/check-the-encoding-of-text-in-sqlite) for a discussion of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks. The database had its encoding as UTF-8. The problem turned out to be the CSV file encoding not being set as UTF-8 before import.